# "Pos Pred Value" in caret's confusionMatrix returns unexpected NA

Tags: r

Given a dataframe with three different factors I would like to compute precision using the confusionMatrix function in the library `caret`. For my given example I would expect a precision (=`Pos Pred Value`) of 1 for the class "positive". However, I am getting "NA" instead. Am I making a error somewhere?

```
> temp
Source: local data frame [12 x 2]

        ref     pred
     (fctr)   (fctr)
1  positive positive
2  positive positive
3  positive  neutral
4  positive positive
5  positive positive
6  positive positive
7  positive positive
8  positive positive
9  positive positive
10 positive positive
11 positive positive
12 positive positive
> confusionMatrix(temp$pred, temp$ref)$byClass
                Sensitivity Specificity Pos Pred Value ...
Class: negative          NA   1.0000000             NA ...
Class: neutral           NA   0.9166667             NA ...
Class: positive   0.9166667          NA             NA ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PPV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values) depends on the prevalence (aka known rate of the event aka the prior probability) as well as sensitivity and specificity. Since you can't estimate the sensitivity or specificity in some classes, you can't know the PPV.

Max